# Jetpack Compose Number Input in to TextField

Tags: android, user-input, textfield, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am currently unable to capture user input in to a textfield when the KeyboardType of the keyboard is set to KeyboardType.Number.

If the keyboard is set to KeyboardType.Text, the Textfield updates as expected, however when set to KeyboardType.Number, the Textfield fails to update.

Why is this? and how can I change my code so that when the Textfield is clicked, a Number Keyboard is displayed ,and, when numbers are pressed, the relevant numbers are updated in the Textfield.

The following code DOES NOT update the textfield (When set to KeyboardType.Number)...

```
@Composable
fun MyNumberField() {

    var text = remember { mutableStateOf("")}

    val change : (String) -> Unit = { it ->
        value.value = it
    }

    TextField(
        value = text.value,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
        onValueChange = change
    )

}
```

The following code does update the textfield (When set to KeyboardType.Text)...

```
@Composable
fun MyNumberField() {

    var text = remember { mutableStateOf("")}

    val change : (String) -> Unit = { it ->
        text.value = it
    }

    TextField(
        value = value.value,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text),
        onValueChange = change
    )

}
```

Many Thanks

Comment: what does it mean *capture user input in to a textfield* ?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti The value of 'text' is not updated when numbers are inputted by the user when the keyboard type is set to KeyboardType.Number, however, the value is updated when the keyboard type is set to KeyboardType.Text

Comment: which version of compose are you using? It should work without issues on beta07

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Ah yes! Thanks alot, I was using Beta01 still!

Comment: Did updating to the latest (beta7) solve your issue ?

Comment: Anyone else facing similar issue after the latest update ?

Answer (score 16):

You are supposed to update `text.value`, not `value.value` there is a typo in your code change it to this.

```
@Composable
fun MyNumberField() {

    var text = remember { mutableStateOf("")}

    val change : (String) -> Unit = { it ->
        value.value = it    // you have this which is not correct and I don't think it even compiled
        text.value = it  // it is supposed to be this 
    }

    TextField(
        value = text.value,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
        onValueChange = change
    )

}
```

Comment: it allows to type dot and comma

Answer (score 0):

I would go a step further and use a MutableIntState and also check that all entered text is an Int.

```
@Composable
fun MyNumberField() {

    var number = remember { mutableIntStateOf("")}

    val change : (String) -> Unit = { it ->
        number = it.toIntOrNull() ?: number 
    }
 ...
```