# Compose TextField not triggering onvalueChange when KeyboardType is Number

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

When i set keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number) or even KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number), the onValueChange callback is not triggerd.

##### Versions:

| software | version |
| --- | --- |
| Compose compiler | 1.4.6 |
| Compose UI | 1.4.3 |
| Kotlin | 1.8.2 |

##### Kotlin code:

```kotlin
import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedTextField
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardType

@Composable
fun TestNumberInput() {
    var numbers by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    OutlinedTextField(
        value = numbers, 
        onValueChange = { 
            Log.i("TEST", "numbers: $numbers")
            numbers = it
        }, 
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
    )
}
```

There is already [a question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67687674/jetpack-compose-number-input-in-to-textfield) about this problem but the cause seems to come from somewhere else then the problem i have.

Comment: It seems there is no problem in the code. I just tested the code with versions you provided, onValueChange is correctly invoked.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that when keyboardType is number, Activity.dispatchKeyEvent is triggerd which i have overriden. I couldn't found this in the documentation , but maybe this is some sort of standard.  Anyway I have adjusted  dispatchKeyevent to handle the numeric keyboard and now the value is send to the TextField.